# autocad 3d object animation with iPhone

Tags: iphone, animation, 3d, autocad

I need to know what autocad extentions are used in iPhone development, actually, I need to create an iPhone animation with autocad 3d objects.

thanks

Comment: That is going to be hell on the phone you're trying to do that on. I've worked on desktops that struggle rendering 3D AC drawings. There are probably better ways of doing that, but if you need a full service parametric modeling software package; may I suggest Pro-E Wildfire 5.0 (Creo Elements)? The models are much lighter, it's easier to use, and user defined animations are much easier. ALL IMHO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019534/beginners-guide-to-3d-programming-in-iphone-sdk).  It should point you in the right direction if you are hoping to render 3d content on the phone.  I don't know what to tell you wrt autocad though...but I think I can confidently say that trying to render content from autocad files is going to be unnecessarily tough.